# Recurring billing with Stripe - will Subscriptions suffice?

Tags: stripe-payments

My application allows a customer to purchase **credits** for later in-app use.

I want to enable customers to buy credits throughout the month, and only get billed at the end of the month.

Should I be using a Stripe Subscription at an **amount that equals the price of one credit**, and change the **quantity** according to the number of credits the customer purchased?

(After a successful invoice - I'll **reset the subscription quantity to 0**)

Is there a better solution? Perhaps some clever method of using Stripe Checkout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proposed approach sounds reasonable.

I've not tried it but an alternative I can think of would use a free plan and the Invoice Items part of the API.

1. Create a free plan with amount with [amount field](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_plan-amount) set to 0. As far as I can see from the docs, all the subscription lifecycle webhooks should be triggered for Customers who're subscribed to the plan.
2. Through the month, create [InvoiceItems](https://stripe.com/docs/api#invoiceitems) for the Customer. According to the docs, at the end of the billing cycle, those InvoiceItems are added to the customer's invoice.

> Sometimes you want to add a charge or credit to a customer but only actually charge the customer's card at the end of a regular billing cycle. This is useful for combining several charges to minimize per-transaction fees or having Stripe tabulate your usage-based billing totals.

Beyond that, you'll want to consider if you should have Stripe generate/email your invoices.

Answer (score 0):

**I don't think this is the way to go**, because subscriptions are billed **the first time** among other things.

The recommanded way is: [stripe doc: Place a hold on a card](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/capture-later)

### summary

- You first ask authorization for a certain amount (the max amount). Eg: 1000$
- Your custommer buy 50 credits in the month
- At the end of the month you charge the customer for 50$ (it can not be greater that the maximum you authorized in the first step)

That's all :)